# Tailwind issue on monorepo with Next app directory,Tailwind issue on monorepo with Next app directory

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, monorepo

Tailwind issue on monorepo with Next app directory

I have something like a dashboard that have 2 types of user: **client and admin**
and in my monorepo I have 2 packages for them, plus I have reusable package **components**

All these packages use Tailwind for styling, with the same setup

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/components/**/\*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    "./components/**/\*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
};
```

Admin already migrated to Next app directory
The client still use the page directory

in both packages, I use default css import

```
import @/styles/tailwind.css
import mylib/dist/tailwind.css
```

This setup works fine for the Client, and I don't have any problem with it
but
For Admin package some of styles doesn't work

The last thing that helped me add a prefix to the component lib config

**prefix: 'tw-**'

this solution works but I don't want to add to all my classnames prefix in the whole lib

and it is odd why everything works without prefix in the client package

mb I have a better approach to adding to all classes prefixes (while building app mb)?
or mb I should setup it better somehow